# Linq to SQL to ObservableCollection for treeview in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, bindable-linq

I have some Linq to SQL table classes that are joined together. I currently have it bound to a treeview using just the LINQ to SQL query. It works, but it doesn't show when stuff is added or removed from the database.

I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged but it isn't updating the treeview.

I also tried using Bindable Linq, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I found an example of a way to easily create ObservableCollections without having to create more classes: [jimlynn.wordpress.com/2008/12/09/using-observablecollection-with-linq/](http://jimlynn.wordpress.com/2008/12/09/using-observablecollection-with-linq/), (which is kind of important because I have a future project looming that will require interacting with a lot of tables (30 or so) and just creating the Linq to SQL classes is going to be a pain).

```
    Property ModelQuery As ObservableCollection(Of dbModels) = New ObservableCollection(Of dbModels)().PopulateFrom(From mm In tblModels.AsBindable Order By mm.ModelName)
```

Is this a good way to go, or am I going to have to create a separate ObservableCollection and maintain them both in code. If I'm going to use this binding stuff,  I'm really looking for a way to have stuff just linked together so I don't have to update multiple structures whenever a change is made.

Main table:

```
<Table(Name:="Models")> Public Class dbModels
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Private _changed As Boolean
    Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Protected Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal Propertyname As String)
        If Not Propertyname.Contains("Changed") Then
            Changed = True
        End If
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(Propertyname))
    End Sub
    Public Property Changed() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _changed
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            If _changed <> value Then
                _changed = value
                OnPropertyChanged("Changed")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ModelID As Integer
    <Column(Storage:="_ModelID", DbType:="int IDENTITY NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey:=True, IsDbGenerated:=True, Name:="ModelID")> _
    Public Property ModelID() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._ModelID
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Me._ModelID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ModelName As String
    <Column(Storage:="_ModelName", DbType:="Varchar(200)", Name:="ModelName")> _
    Public Property ModelName() As String
        Get
            Return Me._ModelName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me._ModelName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ModelYears As EntitySet(Of dbModelYears) = New EntitySet(Of dbModelYears)
    <Association(Storage:="_ModelYears", DeleteRule:="CASCADE", OtherKey:="ModelID")> _
    Public Property ModelYears As EntitySet(Of dbModelYears)
        Get
            Return _ModelYears
        End Get
        Set(value As EntitySet(Of dbModelYears))
            _ModelYears.Assign(value)
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Joined table:

```
<Table(Name:="ModelYears")> Public Class dbModelYears
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Private _changed As Boolean
    Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Protected Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal Propertyname As String)
        If Not Propertyname.Contains("Changed") Then
            Changed = True
        End If
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(Propertyname))
    End Sub
    Public Property Changed() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _changed
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            If _changed <> value Then
                _changed = value
                OnPropertyChanged("Changed")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ModelYearID As Integer
    <Column(Storage:="_ModelYearID", DbType:="int IDENTITY NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey:=True, IsDbGenerated:=True, Name:="ModelYearID")> _
    Public Property ModelYearID() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._ModelYearID
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Me._ModelYearID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ModelID As Integer
    <Column(Storage:="_ModelID", DbType:="int", Name:="ModelID")> _
    Public Property ModelID() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._ModelID
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            Me._ModelID = value
        End Set
    End Property

 Private _ModelYear As String
    <Column(Storage:="_ModelYear", DbType:="Varchar(50)", Name:="ModelYear")> _
    Public Property ModelYear() As String
        Get
            Return Me._ModelYear
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me._ModelYear = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` or using `ObservableCollection` wont notify you of changes in the database. You are going to have to execute the query every time you want to retrieve new data from the database.
Alternatively you could possibly use [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) to set up a query notification dependency between your application and an instance of SQL Server.

**EDIT:**
From comments.
To hook up the `PropertyChanged` event of the items in the collection.

```
For Each item As var In itemsCollection
    Dim notifyItem = TryCast(item, INotifyPropertyChanged)
    If item IsNot Nothing Then
        AddHandler notifyItem.PropertyChanged, AddressOf ItemChanged
    End If
Next

Public Sub ItemChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
  'Handle event
End Sub
```

Comment: Does that mean that it won't notify me if I make changes in the instance I'm running, or that it won't notify me if someone else makes changes to the database from another computer? Is there a reason it wouldn't see the changes if I trigger the property changed in the class?

Comment: It wont notify you of changes made in the database. If you make in memory changes to the `ObservableCollection` it will notify you.

Comment: Is there a reason it's not notifying me then? Would it make a difference if the change was made in a child class that's joined with an entityset?

Comment: If you want notification of changes to the items inside the collection you are going to have to iterate over the collection add hook of the events.

Comment: Ok, that sounds reasonable... pointers on where to start looking for info so I can learn that? I'm still pretty noob with wpf in some areas.

Comment: Definitely looks interesting... just trying to figure out how to apply it to my case. Does the for loop fit into the Linq class, or does it belong outside of the class? Sorry I'm slow at this.